# How can I force GNU Screen to flush its logfile?

Tags: gnu-screen, daemon, gameserver

I am using [Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) like this:

```
screen -L -dm -S session1 -c "./game_server -options"
```

to wrap around game servers. I log their output to a file and can send them input with:

```
screen -r session1 -p0 -X "stuff \"this into input^M\""
```

The timeout between log file flushes can be specified in the configuration file (10 seconds in my case).

The problem I have is that I can't force screen to flush output to the logfile. For example, after I send a "status" command to a game server, the game server prints some information, but it takes at least 10 seconds to add that to the log file.

I have tried sending:

```
screen -r session1 -p0 -X "logfile flush 1"
```

But it doesn't react to that. I've also tried *flush 0* with no luck.

I wouldn't want to always log with a timeout of 1 second; it's only really needed after receiving a command. Note that I'm paranoid about performance here because the session is running a game server after all.

How can I force screen to flush output to the logfile? Is there a way to do what I need (log output to file and send commands to input) other than with screen, maybe with a FIFO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
screen -r session1 -X colon "logfile flush 1^M"
```

`logfile flush 1` isn't actually a screen command, but `colon` is.  The next thing you pass is the argument to it which has to be quoted and the ^M at the end should actually be a Ctrl-M.  Ctrl-V followed by Ctrl-M will generally do the trick for entering an actual Ctrl-M.

Comment: Thank you very much. Also, I was having problems with Ctrl-V Ctrl-M: it did print ^M in the command line, but then simply printed ^M in the screen window. Might have been the quotes. I ended up using this: screen ... -X stuff "$(printf '%b' 'this into input\015')".

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same need as you. `Logfile flush` is a valid command to send to screen - however, it doesn't need to be quoted, and you can also set it to 0 for instant flushing.

Change your line to

```
screen -r session1 -p0 -X logfile flush 0
```

Make sure to change it back when you are done reading from the log file though

```
screen -r session1 -p0 -X logfile flush 10
```

The default is 10 seconds, but you can set it to whatever you think is appropriate.